# How can use vuejs in laravel for web-page that need SEO support?

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I am bit confused to use PHP `laravel` `vuejs` template for my dynamic website. Even JavaScript framework is not SEO friendly and how can use this in `laravel` for an dynamic website that need SEO.

I got reference from google and stack overflow questions that need to use an `API` based architecture.  I don`t want to create it as an `API` based `laravel` and `NUXTJS` front end.

How can use `vuejs` search engine optimization friendly in laravel ?

Comment: If you dont want to use Server Side rendering but you want to use a JS framework that renders elements your only option is to use a service like prerender. Though google is pretty good now with JS.

Comment: So using vuejs in laravel have no support for Server Side rendering... So how will do prerecording, am new on this. Please guide me @MichaelMano

Comment: https://github.com/spatie/laravel-server-side-rendering - You can do SSR with laravel. Prerender is just a paid service that caches your pages for search engines and social media.

Comment: Another way to use the stack Laravel + prerendered Vue.js app is to use Nuxt.js, hosted and prerendered on free plaftorms such as Netlify, and write only your API on Laravel. It's an incredibly flexible and powerfull combination. However, mind that it is much more work and you'll have to mantain two separate codebases so do your math and figure out if it's worth the hassle... If for your project is not mandatory to have an hyper dynamic frontend I would rather use plain blade templates for seo purposes. Often full JS apps are overused.

Comment: @MiCc83 Yes am trying Nuxt.js . Hope that is the solution for this...